# linux pipe how to print values one step back

Tags: linux, awk, pipe

I think there might be a solution to this problem. I want to print the number of lines before and after filtering in one linux pipe.

```
#befor filtering, printing number of all lines
less /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1, $3}' | wc -l 

#after filtering, printing number of filtered lines
less /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1, $3}' | awk '$2 >= 47{print $0}' | wc -l
```

But I can not figure out how can I get these two values from one line of code. Any suggestion will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk -F: '{i++} $3>=47 {j++} END {print "total="i,"\n>46="j}' /etc/passwd
total=40
>46=23
```

`i++` increment i for every line, gives total.
`$3>=47 {j++}` Test if field 3 is larger than 46
`print "total="i,"\n>46="j`   Prints i and j

Short as possible: Test for `larger than 46`, since its equal to `larger than and equal to 47`

```
awk -F: '{i++}$3>46{j++}END{print i,j}' /etc/passwd
```

As Ed points out `NR` (Number of Records) does contain total records.
So even shorter:

```
awk -F: '$3>46{j++}END{print NR,j}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: And if you want to present it as a table it can be like this: `{ echo Before After ; awk -F: '{i++} $3 >= 47 {j++} END {print i,j}' /etc/passwd; } | column -t`

Comment: @MostafaHussein  Its just two numbers so a table is hardly needed.

Comment: Amazing @Jotne.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `i`, just print `NR` in the END

Comment: @MostafaHussein if a table was desirable and you wanted to provide headers, you don't need to add an echo to do that when you're using awk since awk can also print strings.

Comment: @EdMorton `echo` for the headers not for `awk`, so if we tried to remove `echo` it will raise an error.

Comment: @MostafaHussein my point is that `{ echo "foo bar"; awk '{print}' file }` will produce exactly the same output as `awk 'BEGIN{print "foo bar"} {print}' file`.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can "split" pipes using `tee` and file descriptors:

```
less /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1, $3}' | tee >(awk '$2 >= 47{print $0}' >(wc -l) | wc -l)
```

Comment: I think the output needs to be reversed, because on my machine i see "the after value" before "the before value"

Comment: It printed number of lines for both before and after filtering. But I am not sure why it is printing the table.